# The value is stored as a temp file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to upload a file and store the associated path in the database.

However, when I upload it in the databse, I get the path to a temporary folder. When I dump the result of the upload, I get the right path.

So, instead of getting `banners/myfile.jpg` I get something like: `C:\xampp\tmp`.

Here is my code, when I dump $path and $this after assigning the value of path to banner, I get the right value. When it's saved, it is saved in the database as the temp folder.

```
// SAVE BANNER IN EMPLOYER MODEL
    public function saveBanner($data) {
        if(isset($data['banner'])) {
            $banner = $data['banner'];
            if(isset($this->banner) && Storage::disk('public')->exists($this->banner)) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($this->banner);
            }
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('banners', $banner);
            $this->banner = $path;
        }
    }
 
// UPDATE CONTROLLER
 
    public function update(UpdateEmployerRequest $request) {
        $data = $request->validated();
        $user = getEmployer()->user;
        $employer = getEmployer();
        if(app('hash')->check($request->password, $user->password) === true || auth()->user()->isEmployee()) {
            $employer->saveLogo($data);
            $employer->saveBanner($data);
            $employer->fill($data);
            $employer->save();
            return redirect()->route('employers.edit');
        } else {
            $errors = new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag();
            $errors->add('password',  __('validation.custom.password_update'));
            return redirect()->route('employers.edit')->withErrors($errors);
        }
 
    }
 
// RULES 
 
 
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Requests;
 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Rules\PhoneNumber;
 
class UpdateEmployerRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
 
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'description' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'color' => 'nullable|regex:/#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}/',
            'logo' => 'nullable|file|image|max:10000|dimensions:max_height=500,max_width=500',
            'banner' => 'nullable|file|image|max:10000',
            'contact_firstname' => 'required|min:2',
            'contact_lastname' => 'required|min:2',
            'contact_firstname' => 'required|min:2',
            'contact_lastname' => 'required|min:2',
            'civic' => 'required|string',
            'city' => 'required|string',
            'enterprise_number' => 'required|string',
            'revenue' => 'required|numeric',
            'hiring_volume' => 'required|numeric',
            'phone_number' => ['required', new PhoneNumber()],
            'contact_phone_number' => ['required', new PhoneNumber()],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me figure out why the good path is replaced by the tmp path when saving to db?

Here is the code for the logo (works properly):

```
// SAVE LOGO
    public function saveLogo($data) {
        if(isset($data['logo'])) {
            $logo = $data['logo'];
            if(isset($this->logo) && Storage::disk('public')->exists($this->logo)) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($this->logo);
            }
            $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('logos', $logo);
            $this->logo = $path;
        }
    }

// (same controller and rules)
```

Comment: Did you check your `banners` directory file save or not?

Comment: @sta Yep, the file is stored at the right place. The value of $path is the path to the file. It breaks when I try to save this path in the database.

Comment: You save this file with `update` function?

Comment: @sta Yeah,  it's the profile update. I don't allow them to upload pictures as signup. I added how I upload logo (and it works just fine).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add "banner" to my guarded fields. Laravel would set the value of "banner" using the data validated and not the path created.